# Promoted Links - New Information

Tags: promoted-links

I have created some promoted links tiles that currently show on the home page of my site. I would love for the tile to show when I new document is uploaded. Is there a way for this to happen?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[Promoted Link](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-promoted-links-list-app-part-1)

1. Click on New document -->When upload form is open, right click on it and then click properties. You will get the URL in properties window.
2. Add that URL in Promoted list item.
3. Add this Promoted link list in home page as a web part.

Comment: How can I get menu list whenever I hover on my tile? Is this possible?